# User editing own Active Directory data

Tags: asp.net, python, active-directory

How can I build a web page that allows a logged on user of a Windows 2003 domain change details of his account (probably just First Name, Surname, and Phone number)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Python-AD](http://code.google.com/p/python-ad/) (Python Active Directory) which offers the bindings you'll want for communicating with the AD server.

As for the very broad "how can I build a web page" portion of your request, SO has plenty of questions/answers on good web frameworks in python :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11204.html